# (Adjust touch screen presure threshold) Have touch panel on touch screen respond to lower presure

Tags: touchscreen

A customer of mine had a computer that died, with a touch screen on it (IIyama ProLite T2252MSC).
I had the customer put the touch screen on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, and customer now complains the touch screen barely reacts to touch, you need to press very hard to get a reaction.

I don't know if that screen conforms to [Windows Touchscreen Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchscreen-required-hid-top-level-collections), nor do I know much about USB HID touchscreens in general, but from the link before, it seems that a touch screen may report presure.

Is there way to adjust how much presure would be needed to trigger a "click"?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for things about Weida Hi-Tech which seems to be the touch panel manufacturer, I came across this [forum thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=179663).

Somebody there suggests adding "usbhid.mousepoll=0" to /boot/cmdline.txt, tried it, it fixed the reported issue.